# Best way to count and group blog-like results

Tags: php, mysql

We have a database of news posts on our site that has some 3000 rows (one for each post, dating back to 2001). Each has a unix timestamp indicating it's post date.

I want to have an archive page that shows a summary of how many posts were on that given month. So grouped by year, then month

```
2011
January (13 posts)
February (25 posts)

2012 
March (30 posts)
```

etc.

What's the most efficient way of doing this? I had a mess of code before that had two for loops (year, then month) which would query the database for each month and count how many posts were made then. It was, not surprisingly, incredibly slow.

Any tips on how to group the data and avoid hitting the database for every single month.

Comment: if you provide your tables structure with some sample data, i'll give you query

Comment: Why are you not keeping archived count in a separate table with columns : year, month, count. ?

Comment: Honestly, just because I never really considered it. It does seem to make the most sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best handled with a aggregated table in the database for keeping statistics on a monthly basis. You can have a simple table with 3 columns.

```
Year | Month | Count
```

on a daily basis you run a simple aggregated query counting the number of posts for that month (using a filter) and update the table above. It will be fast and clean.